# Blender animation to XNA distortion bug

Tags: c#, animation, matrix, xna

I followed the instructions on the following video: **www.youtube.com/watch?v=SissgQ0IXvk**

I'm using XNA 4.0 and Blender 2.69

I export the model with animation to a .FBX file.

The animation is a man waving

Here is what it looks like in Blender:

**i.stack.imgur.com/481r9.jpg**

And here is how it renders in XNA:

**i.stack.imgur.com/iWk1E.jpg**

The arm where the animation occurs is greatly distorted.

I believe the error occurs in the AnimationPlayer class:

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Helper used by the Update method to refresh the WorldTransforms data.
    /// </summary>
    public void UpdateWorldTransforms(Matrix rootTransform)
    {
        // Root bone.
        worldTransforms[0] = boneTransforms[0] * rootTransform;

        // Child bones.
        for (int bone = 1; bone < worldTransforms.Length; bone++)
        {
            int parentBone = skinningDataValue.SkeletonHierarchy[bone];

            worldTransforms[bone] = boneTransforms[bone] *
                                         worldTransforms[parentBone];
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Helper used by the Update method to refresh the SkinTransforms data.
    /// </summary>
    public void UpdateSkinTransforms()
    {
        for (int bone = 0; bone < skinTransforms.Length; bone++)
        {
            skinTransforms[bone] = skinningDataValue.InverseBindPose[bone] *
                                        worldTransforms[bone];
        }
    }
```

I think the bug can be fixed by editing the code above, I just don't know how to do it.
Can somebody help me fix this distortion bug?

Here is a link to the project source code:

**www.mediafire.com/download/ps5ocf1nxbfgrru/SkinningSample_4_0.zip**

Here is a link to the Blender file:

**www.mediafire.com/download/vrt8h1p83vkd76g/wave.blend**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. XNA's content pipeline doesn't seem to be able to handle animated FBXs correctly. So XNA has a bug. Luckily Blender 2.68a and older has a "fix" for this. Just check "XNA rotation animation hack" when exporting the FBX.

Answer (score 1):

XNA has been discontinued so this 'hack' has been removed. Monogame is often seen as a replacement but it still has not solved this problem.